# How build a advanced search with checkbox using Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, ransack

how I build a advanced search how this image:

[image: advanced search with checkboxes]

I have my controller, very basic yet:

```
def index
    @q = Product.ransack(params[:q])
    @products = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end
```

And have my view:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name" %>
  <br />
  <%= f.search_field :name_cont %>
  <br />
  <%= f.label :brand, "Brand" %>
  <br />
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :brand, Product.all, :id, :brand %>
  <br />
  <%= f.label :hd, "HD" %>
  <br />
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :hd, Product.all, :id, :hd %>
  <br />
  <%= f.label :ram, "RAM" %>
  <br />
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :ram, Product.all, :id, :ram %>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

But, the only thing that worked on search is the input name. And I have two problems. 1º The checkboxes don't worked. 2º Some checkboxes is repeting because I put Product.all, but too put distinct, but nothing worked =/
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following for brand, hd and ram

```
<% Product.pluck('distinct brand').each do |brand| %>
 <%= check_box_tag('q[brand_cont_any][]', brand ) %>
 <%= brand %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yep, now show just one and don't repeat more, but when click in Sarch, nothing happen. The url is ugly too: ?utf8=✓&q%5Bname_cont%5D=&q%5Bproducts_brand%5D%5B%5D=Samsung&q%5Bproducts_brand%5D%5B%5D=CCE&q%5Bproducts_hd%5D%5B%5D=500+GB&q%5Bproducts_hd%5D%5B%5D=1+TB&q%5Bproducts_ram%5D%5B%5D=4+GB&q%5Bproducts_ram%5D%5B%5D=8+GB&commit=Search

Comment: my mistake it should be q[brand_cont_any][] no need of model name, I have updated the answer above