# Advanced Search in Rails 5 with checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, advanced-search

I'm trying to make an advanced form in Rails.

I have two tables: Category and Tip. Each Tip has several Categories, and a Category can have several Tips. All relationships are done correctly (checked in console).

My goal is to create a form where a user can search for Tips according to one (or more) categories he has selected. I would like to do this in the form of a check box.

Do you have a tutorial to recommend? I'm trying to find some, but either they're under an old version of Rails with obsolete functions, or it doesn't meet my request.

After that, I would like to combine several search criteria (by city, by price range etc.).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: [Possible the below question can help you to create the advanced search form with check boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953049/how-build-a-advanced-search-with-checkbox-using-ransack)

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'm answer below for more details